# Signal handling difference "shutdown -r" and "reboot" in Linux

Tags: linux, signals, reboot

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 LTS Linux Desktop. I found there is a difference in the signal handling during `shutdown -r` and `reboot`.

I built an `a.out`, which will capture the `SIGTERM`, and post some messages. With `shutdown -r`, `a.out` can get the `SIGTERM`, and post the messages. But with `reboot` (and `reboot -f`), `a.out` did NOT get the `SIGTERM` or post the messages.

What is the difference between `shutdown -r` and `reboot` in Linux. And who/when sends the `SIGTERM` to all other processes.

Thanks.